# need a 24 bits type in objc

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I need to a variable which holds a 24 bits value, what should I use ?
Also, do you know a list of all available types in Objc?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C has exactly the same types as plain C. All object references and the id type are technically pointers.
The size of integer datatypes (`char` … `long long`) is not defined but their relation and minimum size is.

- The smallest integer data type guaranteed to hold 24bit is `long int` which must be at least 32bit.
- `int` may be 16bit on some systems.
- 3 `char`s will be at least 24bit since a `char` must have 8bit or more.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `int`. It will hold 24 bits. (32, actually)

Comment: I'm quite sure that's what he really wants.

Answer (score 1):

An array of 3 unsigned chars will be 24 bits (on most systems).